# What happens when the price goes lower than stop limit

Tags: limit-order

Suppose Stop price is 45 and Stop Limit is 46. What happens if the price went far lower than 45 and never recovered?

I suppose I would lose huge because the order would only get executed at 46 or higher (favourable = more profit for the seller). Is it correct?

So to limit the loss, use stop order without stop limit is the better way?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Investopedia - What's the Difference Between a Stop and a Limit Order?](https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/04/022704.asp):

> ### Stop-Limit Order
>
> A stop-limit order consists of two prices: a stop price and a limit
> price. This order type can be used to activate a limit order to buy or
> sell a security once a specific trigger price or stop has been met.
>
> For example, imagine you purchase shares at $100 and expect the stock
> to rise. You could place a stop-limit order to sell the shares if your
> forecast was wrong. If you set the stop price at $90 and the limit
> price as $90.50, the order will be activated if the stock trades at
> $90 or worse. However, a limit order will be filled only if the limit
> price you selected is available in the market. If the stock drops
> overnight to $89 per share, that is below your stop price, so the
> order will be activated, but it will not be filled immediately because
> there are no buyers at your limit price of $90.50 per share. The stop
> price and the limit price can be the same with this order type.
>
> ### Stop Market Order
>
> A stop market order will turn into a traditional market order once
> your stop price is met or exceeded.
>
> In the previous example, the stop-limit order was not filled at $90.50
> because that price was not available in the market when the stock
> dropped through the stop price overnight.
>
> A stop market order is triggered once the price is equal to or beyond
> $90 and in this example will be executed at $89 or the best
> alternative price. In these two scenarios, the stop order is used to
> control losses, and both orders are sometimes referred to as a "stop
> loss" by traders.